# Nest vdev in a ZFS pool, is that possible?

Tags: zfs

I have now a Linux server running with 3x4TB in RAID5. I am running a bit short in space and I am looking into solutions. The easy one would be to get a new 4TB drive and just add it.

Well, I also happen to have some disks (1x1TB, 1x2TB, 2x3TB) laying around and I would like to put them to good use.

I had a look at ZFS and now I would like to ask whether I got it right and whether the below strange arrangement would be possible.

I would like to combine 1x2TB disk and 1x1TB disk in one 3TB vdev using stripe mode.

Then, I would combine 2x3TB with this vdev in RAIDz1, giving me a 6TB vdev

Beside that, I would combine 3x4TB in RAIDz1 giving a 8TB vdev

then both the 6TB vdev and the 8TB vdev would be striped in a pool of 14TB.

My big question is whether it is possible to use a vdev as a component of a vdev?

And, would that be a hassle to later on replace the 3TB vdev by an actual 3TB disk? Or should I simply straight away buy a new 3TB?

Answer (score 1):

That's all me, I post a question I could not find answer till then and that makes the solution appears before my eyes...

So, no, it is not possible to nest vdev, in my case, the best would be indeed to go straight to buy a new 3TB drive and create 2 vdev in RAIDz1 and stripe them.

A very similar question [here](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/362377-zfs-question-about-nested-raidz/)